# Tkinter timer to start at 0 on button click

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to create a timer that starts at 0 when a user presses a button and stop at whatever time it has displayed when the user presses the button again. So far, all of the questions user `after` that looks at the current time and updates in seconds from whatever time it is like so:

```
def timer(self):
    now = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    self.label.configure(text=now)
    self.after(1000, self.timer)
```

But I would like to start at zero, display the minutes and seconds. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: So what's the problem?  Store the current time somewhere when the button is pressed, subtract that from the current time when updating your timer.  Or, simply count up by one every time your `self.after(1000,...)` routine executes, but that's going to drift over time.

Comment: Wow I didn't even think to subtract the time! That should work. If you make that an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple stopwatch GUI. There's some room for improvement. ;)

```
import tkinter as tk
from time import time

class Stopwatch:
    def __init__(self):
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.title('Stopwatch')

        self.display = tk.Label(root, text='00:00', width=20)
        self.display.pack()

        self.button = tk.Button(root, text='Start', command=self.toggle)
        self.button.pack()

        self.paused = True
        root.mainloop()

    def toggle(self):
        if self.paused:
            self.paused = False
            self.button.config(text='Stop')
            self.oldtime = time()
            self.run_timer()
        else:
            self.paused = True
            self.oldtime = time()
            self.button.config(text='Start')

    def run_timer(self):
        if self.paused:
            return
        delta = int(time() - self.oldtime)
        timestr = '{:02}:{:02}'.format(*divmod(delta, 60))
        self.display.config(text=timestr)
        self.display.after(1000, self.run_timer)

Stopwatch()
```

The `toggle` method toggles the stopwatch on or off. The `run_timer` method updates the `display` Label with the time since the timer started, in minutes & seconds. For more accuracy, reduce the `.after` delay to say, 500, or 100. That will do unnecessary (and invisible) updates to the Label, but the displayed time will be a little more accurate, and the GUI will feel a little more responsive.

Comment: @Wolfgang Python doesn't actually have declarations, but the `self.oldtime` attribute is assigned in the `toggle` method. This is perfectly safe because we don't attempt to access `self.oldtime` until after it's been created. But if you're not comfortable with that, feel free to assign it in the `__init__` method, eg `self.oldtime = None`; there's no point assigning a time value to it prematurely.

Answer (score 1):

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.root = master

        self.parent = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.parent.pack(fill = tk.BOTH)
        self.parent.config(bg = "black")

        self.now         = time.time()
        self.buttonVar   = tk.IntVar()
        self.buttonCycle = False
        self.buttonVar.set(0)

        self.button = tk.Button(root,
                                textvariable = self.buttonVar,
                                command      = self.updateButton)
        self.button.pack(fill = tk.BOTH)

        self.button_cycle()


    def updateButton(self):
        if self.buttonCycle:
            self.buttonCycle = False
            self.now = time.time()
        elif not self.buttonCycle:
            self.buttonCycle = True

    def button_cycle(self):
        if self.buttonCycle:
            now            = time.time()
            timeDifference = int(now - self.now)
            self.buttonVar.set(timeDifference)
        self.root.after(1000, self.button_cycle)

root = tk.Tk()
myApp = GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is there a way I can update a label to show how much time has passed every second?

Comment: ```show how much time has passed every second?``` Well a second would have passed in a second lol - What do you mean?

Comment: lol, fair! I want to have the button pressed and then display each second since 0. So the button is pressed, and the user sees `1` after one second, `2` after two seconds and so on, automatically. If that makes sense.