# Maximum recursion depth exceeded. Trying to create a timer in Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a timer in Tkinter. This is my working example:

```
# GUI packages                                                         
from Tkinter import *                       
from ttk import *           
from tkMessageBox import *  

sec = 0            
#_

class RunMeasurement(Tk):   

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        Tk.style = Style()  
        Tk.title = 'Data sheet creation'

        self.__timeLabel = None

        myFrame = Frame(self)
        myFrame.pack(fill='both')

        self.__timeLabel = Label(myFrame)
        timeButton = Button(myFrame, text='start', command=self.Tick)
        timeButton.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.__timeLabel.grid(row=0, column=1)


    def Tick(self):  

        global sec
        sec += 1     

        self.__timeLabel['text'] = sec
        self.__timeLabel.after(1000, self.Tick)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = RunMeasurement()
    app.mainloop()
```

But if I try to change it a little bit in order to, for example, count each time by 2 or 3 in this way (only corresponding part of the previous code was changed):

```
...
timeButton = Button(myFrame, text='start', command=lambda: self.Tick(3))
...
def Tick(self, index):
   ...
   sec += index
   ...
   self.__timeFrame.after(1000, self.Tick(index))
```

I get this (see the picture) very fast. And then the RuntimeError:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

[image]

**Question**: how to handle this error? And how to create such kind of timer in Tkinter?

Comment: This is similar to calling a function instead of passing the function for a Button command argument, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269096/why-is-button-parameter-command-executed-when-declared)

Comment: FWIW, you may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44372046/4014959) interesting.

Comment: The same problem applies to the `Button`'s `command` as to the callback for `.after`, and it is fixed in the same way too.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the line below

```
self.__timeFrame.after(1000, self.Tick(index))
```

You create recursion by calling `self.Tick` directly. To solve the problem pass `index` as another argument to `after` method like below

```
self.__timeFrame.after(1000, self.Tick, index)
```

Comment: Definitely, I should learn `after` method better. Thank you.