# How do I make a timer stop when a key is pressed in python?

Tags: python, github, tkinter, timer

I am trying to make a timer count with a stopper. I found some code here.

[Tkinter timer to start at 0 on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44372046/tkinter-timer-to-start-at-0-on-button-click)
by PM 2 Ring. I was wondering how to add another function to this code so that when no buttons on the keyboard are pressed the time will automatically keep adding up. However, when either the right arrow or the left arrow is pressed the timer will stop.

Thanks

here is the link to the github

https://github.com/a210082/I2P-Summative

It is the timerbutton code thanks

Comment: That sounds pretty straight-forward. Give me a few minutes. Ah, furas beat me to it.

Comment: Please don't post a link to code on another site. Take the time to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `__init__` you can `bind()` key to function `toggle()`

```
 root.bind('<Left>', lambda event:self.toggle())
```

If you change `def toggle(self):` into `def toggle(self, event=None):` then

```
 root.bind('<Left>', toggle)
```

BTW: [key names](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/key-names.html) for binding